# Difference between [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] and TypeAttributes.SequentialLayout?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection.emit, structlayout

I dynamically build a struct for P/Invoke using

```
const TypeAttributes typeAttributes = TypeAttributes.Public | 
                                      TypeAttributes.SequentialLayout | 
                                      TypeAttributes.UnicodeClass;
var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("MyType", typeAttributes, typeof(ValueType));
```

after that, I construct the [`StructLayoutAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) and add it to the type like this

```
ConstructorInfo structLayoutAttributeConstructorInfo = typeof(StructLayoutAttribute).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(LayoutKind) });

FieldInfo charSetFieldInfo = typeof(StructLayoutAttribute).GetField(nameof(StructLayoutAttribute.CharSet));
CustomAttributeBuilder attr = new CustomAttributeBuilder(structLayoutAttributeConstructorInfo,
                                                         new object[] { LayoutKind.Sequential },
                                                         new FieldInfo[] { charSetFieldInfo },
                                                         new object[] { CharSet.Unicode });
typeBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(structLayoutAttributeBuilder);
```

which is equivalent to setting

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
```

---

Now, the code works *perfectly fine*, regardless of whether or not I apply the `StructLayoutAttribute` to the struct.

- What exactly is the difference between setting an explicit attribute and using the [`TypeAttribute.SequentialLayout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeattributes(v=vs.110).aspx) flag?

Seemingly, setting the attribute is an uncessary redundancy, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSDN documentation for the [`Type.IsLayoutSequential`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.type.islayoutsequential(v=vs.110).aspx) property states the following (emphasis mine):

> For **dynamic types**, you can specify `TypeAttributes.SequentialLayout`
>   when you create the type. **In code**, apply the `StructLayoutAttribute`
>   attribute with the `LayoutKind.Sequential` enumeration value to the
>   type, to specify that layout is sequential.

So for you the relevant part is the `TypeAttributes` flag. Specifying the `StructLayoutAttribute` is redundant or ineffective, respectively.

Comment: Thank you, just what I thought. I just wanted to make sure there won't be unwanted side effects when removing the `StructLayoutAttribute`.